# Concatenating words without quotes in R for groupby in dplyr

Tags: r, group-by, concatenation, dplyr

I have datasets that involve large number of column joins (8-12) and at the same time depending upon the circumstance   1-3 of these columns may not be needed.

Presently I have been writing out these long group-bys using dplyr but with so many columns and changing situations, it is easy to misspell or forget a column.

I'd like to somehow create a variable that goes along with doing this, but I haven't been able to figure out how to due to the quotes that are present when I try to use paste.  Can anyone show me a quick example of how to do this?

For example:

```
  library(dplyr)

    # I want this group-list not to have quotes so I can drop in my group_by below
   my_group_list = paste0("vs"," ","am") #quotes get in the way

   mtcars %>% group_by(my_group_list) %>% summarise(countofvalues = n())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are many columns, we can specify the columns to group from directly subsetting the column names.  In that case, use `group_by_`

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
     group_by_(.dots=names(.)[8:9]) %>% 
     summarise(countofvalues = n())
#     vs    am countofvalues
#   (dbl) (dbl)         (int)
#1     0     0            12
#2     0     1             6
#3     1     0             7
#4     1     1             7
```

The above also works if we have a `vector` of values

```
my_group_list <- c("vs", "am")
mtcars %>%
      group_by_(.dots = my_group_list) %>%
      summarise(countofvalues = n())
#    vs    am countofvalues
#  (dbl) (dbl)         (int)
#1     0     0            12
#2     0     1             6
#3     1     0             7
#4     1     1             7
```

As the OP mentioned that it is not doing the grouping, we can test it by `unite`ing the 'vs' and 'am' columns, use it as grouping variable and then do the `n()`.

```
library(tidyr)
mtcars %>%
      unite(vs_am, vs, am) %>%
      group_by(vs_am) %>% 
      summarise(countofvalues = n())
#  vs_am countofvalues
#  (chr)         (int)
#1   0_0            12
#2   0_1             6
#3   1_0             7
#4   1_1             7
```

Comment: @runningbirds It does group by both.  For example, if you want to check with the canonical way,  `mtcars %>% group_by(vs, am) %>% summarise(countofvalues = n())` the output is the same

Comment: Thank you.  Is there a way to avoid the column position references and instead reference a  named list or vector of values?

Comment: @runningbirds Can you check the output of pasted columns wrt to the one I posted.

Comment: @runningbirds It does work with a vector of values.  Updated the post.

Comment: thank you I truly appreciate your help.  this will save me lots of debugging from typos

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a pretty stale thread, but I happened on to it and found a more recent answer.  You can use `group_by_at()` and tidy select helpers (I found it on this [`dplyr` issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2818)).  For example:

```
my_group_list <- c("vs", "am")
mtcars %>%
   group_by_at(all_of(my_group_list)) %>%
   summarise(countofvalues = n())
# `summarise()` regrouping output by 'vs' (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   vs [2]
#      vs    am countofvalues
#    <dbl> <dbl>         <int>
# 1     0     0            12
# 2     0     1             6
# 3     1     0             7
# 4     1     1             7
```